# Didn't load images when I test version on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use images from resources like that:

```
UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"example.jpg" ];
UIImageView *imageView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image ];
```

When I test it on semulator it's works. But on Iphone no. Also image with size about 10Kb loaded, with size about 100Kb no. Whats wrong?

Comment: 1st thing to check is if your image names have same case - iPhone file system is case sensitive, while MacOS - is not.

Comment: in regards to the memory, jpgs are compressed, so when they're drawn to the screen, they're uncompressed. Uncompressed memory size is larger: width * height * 4.

Comment: Where are you defining position/size of this image?

Comment: -The image names have the same case. I debuged it.
-Why did when I test it on semulator it worked?
-Before add to stage I define position/size of this image

Comment: What version is your iPhone and your xCode AND your iPhone SDK?

Comment: software version 3.0.1 Xcode 3.2 Iphone Sdk 3.1.3

Comment: Are you getting any memory warnings?

Comment: Try doing a complete reset of the simulator? I have had issues where files from a previous install of an app still exist even though I'd accidentally removed them from the project.

Comment: I've found that I have to manually delete the "Build" directory and "Clean" the project for it to compile properly (from time to time) - Also, delete the APP from the iPhone as well.

Comment: I clean. But on simulator I see my image, but on Iphone no.
UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"09.jpg" ];
UIImageView *imageView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image ];
[ _window addSubview:imageView ];

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now. I just make mistake in registry names of files. It was 1.JPG, but I called 1.jpg.